Svelte 5 form data not reactive in submit handler
I am trying to implement a form submit action in Svelte 5 but I am having some issues with reactivity it seems.
<script>
    const formData = $state({
        name: 'abc',
    })

    const saveData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(formData)
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit={saveData}>
    <input type="text" bind:value={formData.name}/>
    <button type="submit">
        Create
    </button>
</form>

<pre>
{formData.name}
</pre>

As expected, the {formData.name} displays the correct value, but the console.log(formData) always outputs abc no matter what I enter in the form. How would I retrieve the most recent value in the submit handler?

In the REPL it works as expected:  REPL

Interesting, you are right. And with console.log($state.snapshot(formData)) it also works, only console.log(formData) displays the old value

What you need to remember is that logging a proxy shows the proxy contents, and said contents contain the original object, unmodified.  In other words:  Initial values given to $state are never modified.

@JoséRamírez and how would I go about accessing the actual data, for example when I want to send it as payload to an API endpoint? Should I explicitly use $state.snapshot in this case?

Just send formData.

But formData will hold the Proxy and when I pass it as payload it will resolve to the initial value as I understood

Do it.  Will work.  Printing a proxy with console.log() looks like the variable didn't change.  That's it.  Print formData.name if you don't believe me.

Ah now I understood, thanks! Feel free to add it as an answer and I will mark the question as resolved

The $state proxies don't change the underlying object, they record changes on top of it, so if you log it you will see the proxy's target which is unchanged.
There should even be a warning in the console, pointing you towards using $inspect or $state.snapshot to get the current value of the state.

Your console.log contained $state proxies. Consider using $inspect(...) or $state.snapshot(...) instead

For the most part, the proxy can be treated like any other object, e.g. if you want to JSON.stringify it to send it via fetch, that should work. But there are APIs and third party code which cannot deal with a proxy, in those cases one should pass a snapshot.
